# Fast series expansion in r

Tags: r, function, performance, math, numerical-methods

I want to generate a series expansion of a smooth function, similar to a Taylor series (but instead using so called Chebyshev polynomials). However, I have not found a fast way to calculate the series expansion given the coefficients. In particular, hard coding the (Chebyshev/Taylor) polynomials seems to be much faster than using existing functions.

Obviously, hard coding the polynomials is not feasible, when the order of approximation is high, but then the question is, how to implement this with a faster code. This is what I have tried:

```
library(mpoly)
library(foreach)

n=5

# Hard code the Chebyshev polynomials of order 1 to 4.

cheb = function(x) {x} # first order Cheb polynomial
cheb2 = function(x) {-1 + 2*x^2} # second order Chebyshev polynomial
cheb3 = function(x) {-3*x+4*x^3} # etc...
cheb4 = function(x) {1-8*x^2+8*x^4}

# Generate Chebyshev polynomials up to order n-1 using chebyshev() from library mpoly

cheb_funs = foreach(n_ind = 1:n) %do% as.function(chebyshev(n_ind-1)) 

# Calculate the series expansion using hard coded polynomials

Cheb_app1 = function(x)
{
  p = x$p
  v = x$v_cheb
  v[1] + v[2]*cheb(p) + v[3]*cheb2(p) + v[4]*cheb3(p) + v[5]*cheb4(p)
} 

# Calculate the series expansion using foreach() and cheb_funs 

Cheb_app2 = function(x)
{
  p = x$p;
  v = x$v_cheb;
  foreach(p_ind = p, .combine = "c") %do%
    (foreach(n_ind = 1:n, .combine = "sum") %do%
       (v[n_ind]*(cheb_funs[[n_ind]](p_ind))))
}

# Microbenchmark

z = list(p = runif(10, -1,1), v_cheb = runif(n, -1,1))
microbenchmark(Cheb_app1(z), Cheb_app2(z))

Unit: microseconds
         expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
 Cheb_app1(z)     3.473     4.011   120.6585     7.955    12.944 11217.96   100
 Cheb_app2(z) 30249.810 33243.943 35605.0237 34127.602 38195.954 47322.77   100
```

Comment: Not everyone is familiar with Chebychev polynomials.  I thinky ou would increase your chances of getting a useful answer if you defined a general Chebychev polynomial in your question, or at least provided a link to it.  Also, what speed of execution would be acceptable to you?  In addition, please consider formatting your code so that the most relevant features of your question are all visible at the same time and without scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to make it more readable. In terms of speed, something close to the speed of the hard coded version would be preferable. Now it is several orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: Very strange. I copied your code, added `library(foreach)`, and got very different results. Using R 4.2.2 on an older computer (i7-6700 CPU) - which version are you using?   
```Unit: nanoseconds  
         expr  min   lq   mean median   uq   max  neval  
 Cheb_app1(z) 3900 4000 4536.5   4100 4300 23800 1000  
 Cheb_app2(z)  200  200  341.0    200  300 15600 1000  
```

Comment: Apparently, I added a typo into the code, when I edited it for readability. Now it should be correct. How does it look like now at your end?

Comment: surely this is the type of question that belongs on Code Review?

Comment: Ok, what is Code Review?

For me it seems the problem is the for loops in foreach() and the way R handles functions in a list. It doesn't seem to be very fast to pull up and evaluate the functions from the list. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with, in the end.

```
library(pracma)
library(microbenchmark)

rm(list = ls())
n=5

# Hard code the Chebyshev polynomials of order 1 to 4.

cheb = function(x) {x} # first order Cheb polynomial
cheb2 = function(x) {-1 + 2*x^2} # second order Chebyshev polynomial
cheb3 = function(x) {-3*x+4*x^3} # etc...
cheb4 = function(x) {1-8*x^2+8*x^4}

# Generate Chebyshev polynomials up to order n-1 using chebyshev() from library mpoly

cheb_funs = foreach(n_ind = 1:n) %do% as.function(chebyshev(n_ind-1)) 

# Calculate the series expansion using hard coded polynomials

Cheb_app1 = function(x)
{
  p = x$p
  v = x$v_cheb
  v[1] + v[2]*cheb(p) + v[3]*cheb2(p) + v[4]*cheb3(p) + v[5]*cheb4(p)
} 

## Another solution ##

power <- function(x, y) sign(x)^y * abs(x)^y
polyMat = chebPoly(n-1)

Cheb_app3 = function(x) {colSums(polyMat %*% t(outer(x$p, (n-1):0, power))*x$v_cheb)}

# Microbenchmark

z = list(p = runif(10, -1,1), v_cheb = runif(n, -1,1))
microbenchmark(Cheb_app1(z),Cheb_app3(z))


Unit: microseconds
         expr    min      lq      mean  median      uq       max neval
 Cheb_app1(z)  3.366  3.6930 115.26432  4.0750  4.3250 11087.282   100
 Cheb_app3(z) 14.305 15.1085  66.43251 15.4965 15.8955  4943.902   100
```

Answer (score 0):

`do.call` adds a little extra overhead, but the timing is very similar for `Cheb_app2` below:

```
library(mpoly)

n <- 5

# Hard code the Chebyshev polynomials of order 1 to 4.

cheb <- function(x) {x} # first order Cheb polynomial
cheb2 <- function(x) {-1 + 2*x^2} # second order Chebyshev polynomial
cheb3 <- function(x) {-3*x+4*x^3} # etc...
cheb4 <- function(x) {1-8*x^2+8*x^4}

cheb_all <- as.function(
  Reduce("+", lapply(0:(n - 1), \(i) chebyshev(i)*mp(paste0("v", i)))),
  varorder = c("x", paste0("v", 0:(n - 1))),
  vector = FALSE
)
#> f(x, v0, v1, v2, v3, v4)
cheb_allc <- compiler::cmpfun(cheb_all)
cheb_funs <- as.function(chebyshev(0:(n - 1)))

Cheb_app1 <- function(x) {
  p <- x$p
  v <- x$v_cheb
  v[1] + v[2]*cheb(p) + v[3]*cheb2(p) + v[4]*cheb3(p) + v[5]*cheb4(p)
}

Cheb_app2 <- function(x) do.call("cheb_all", c(list(x$p), as.list(x$v_cheb)))
Cheb_app2c <- function(x) do.call("cheb_allc", c(list(x$p), as.list(x$v_cheb)))
Cheb_app3 <- function(x) c(cheb_funs(x$p) %*% x$v_cheb)

# Microbenchmark

z <- list(p = runif(10, -1,1), v_cheb = runif(n, -1,1))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Cheb_app1(z),
  Cheb_app2(z),
  Cheb_app2c(z),
  Cheb_app3(z),
  check = "equal",
  times = 1e3
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>           expr  min   lq    mean median   uq    max neval
#>   Cheb_app1(z)  3.2  3.5 14.1300    3.6  3.8 8363.5  1000
#>   Cheb_app2(z)  8.6  8.9 11.0045    9.1  9.3 1515.1  1000
#>  Cheb_app2c(z)  6.4  6.8  8.5209    7.0  7.3 1292.8  1000
#>   Cheb_app3(z) 41.8 43.2 48.3163   44.0 45.3 2089.1  1000
```

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't seem to be working with me, but I get the following error in the `cheb_all` function: "Error: unexpected input in "Reduce("+", lapply(0:(n - 1), \""

Comment: Maybe you have an older version of R. Try changing the backslash to `function`.

Answer (score 0):

***If you don't mind the speed***: You probably can define a function for Chebshev polynomial like below (two options, just for example):

- Recursive representation

```
chebpoly <- Vectorize(function(x, N) {
    if (N %in% c(0, 1)) {
        return(x^N)
    }
    2 * x * Recall(x, N - 1) - Recall(x, N - 2)
}, vectorize.args = "N")
```

- Trigonometric representation

```
chebpoly <- Vectorize(function(x, N) {
    ifelse(abs(x) <= 1,
        cos(N * acos(x)),
        ifelse(x > 1,
            cosh(N * acosh(x)),
            (-1)^N * cosh(N * acosh((-x)))
        )
    )
}, vectorize.args = "N")
```

and then, your `Cheb_app0` can be formulated by

```
Cheb_app <- function(x) {
    p <- x$p
    v <- x$v_cheb
    colSums(v * t(chebpoly(p, seq_along(v) - 1)))
}
```

## Benchmarking

```
set.seed(0)
n <- 5
z <- list(p = runif(10, -1, 1), v_cheb = runif(n, -1, 1))
microbenchmark(
    Cheb_app0(z),
    Cheb_app1(z),
    check = "equivalent"
)
```

gives

```
Unit: microseconds
         expr  min    lq    mean median    uq     max neval
 Cheb_app0(z) 67.0 69.85 148.407  73.45 82.85  6503.1   100
 Cheb_app1(z)  3.4  3.70 174.139   4.20  5.00 16914.2   100
```